# I installed GCC 5.2 from source and I don't know how to uninstall it on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, gcc

The other week I installed GCC 5.2 from source on my ubuntu machine.  I wanted to be able to use fully supported cilk features.  Now I would like to revert back to GCC 4.9.  How can I uninstall GCC 5.2?  I tried using make uninstall but as I understand this is not supported.

Comment: Judging from the comments below, you're snookered — you snookered yourself by not installing the non-standard version in a non-standard place.  I would never install a home-built version of the compiler in the system directories; I install them in `/usr/gcc/v5.2.0` or whatever on most machines, where I create the directory.  (Sometimes it ends up in another file system, such as `/work5/gcc/v5.2.0`, if that's where there's the space, but then there's a symlink in `/usr/gcc` that points to the right place.)

Comment: As to fix: if simply force-installing GCC 4.9 from scratch doesn't do the job, there's always the option of reinstall the entire o/s…not comfortable.  Maybe you can find all the files installed at about the time you installed GCC 5.2.0, and then remove those, and reinstall GCC 4.9.  I've done that for some other software that I installed somewhere I'd rather it hadn't been installed.  It's a pain configuring `find` to find the files installed within 5 minutes, say, of the install time of `gcc`, but it can be done (`-mmin`  for GNU `find`; there are other options too).

Comment: I just ended up reinstalling ubuntu which is pretty easy.  ( I end up doing it every other week for various reasons (mainly due to video drivers) anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you don't need to revert to the system compiler; it is a matter of path. Or set up your [$PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) appropriately. Use `/usr/bin/g++` for the system compiler, and probably `/usr/local/bin/g++` for the compiler you have built from source code from [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

BTW, you probably could use your GCC 5.2 for almost all your future builds

It depends how you have configured it. 
 You should have configured it with  `../gcc-5.2/configure --program-suffix=-my-5.2` then you would use `g++-my-5.2` instead of `g++`

Try to type `g++ -v` (i.e. probably `/usr/local/bin/g++ -v`) to understand how it was configured.

You probably could remove the `gcc` and `g++` binaries under `/usr/local/bin/` and several other files and directories under `/usr/local/` (but be careful).

<sup>Indeed, GCC does not support `make uninstall`</sup>

Comment: I did not add the prefix option when I configured.  I wish I did now.

Comment: I mentionned `--program-suffix`, not `--prefix` (which has a very specific meaning, default is `/usr/local/` but you could have used `$HOME/soft/`)

Comment: /home/chase/workspace/Calc/Debug/Calc: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/chase/workspace/Calc/Debug/Calc)

Comment: (You should edit your question to explain that, not type some incomplete comment)